# access object attribute from parent class

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have an parent structure like below:

- mainwindow (QMainWindow)

  - form1 (QWidget)

    - form2 (QWidget)

Is it possible to access a mainwindow's object attribute, when I'm calling form2?

eg.

```
# I'm in form1, calling form2, and i need add 
# form2 in mdiArea from mainwindow

cad = Form2(self)
self.parent().mdiArea.addSubWindow(cad) 
cad.showMaximized()
```

My code return the following error message:

```
unhandled AttributeError 
"'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'addSubWindow'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mdiArea` is a method of `QMdiSubWindow`.  You need access it as:

```
self.parent().mdiArea().addSubWindow(cad)
```

([Docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmdisubwindow.html#mdiArea))